Unable to update Nuget package microsoft.identity.serviceessentials.aspnetcore to ver 1.28.1
I'm updating the nuget package microsoft.identity.serviceessentials.aspnetcore 1.26.0 to
ver 1.28.1. however I get the below error message in Package Manager Console.
Unable to find package Microsoft.Identity.ServerAuthorization. No packages exist with this id in source(s)
Looks like the dependent package Microsoft.Identity.ServerAuthorization is not available in the feed and I'm unable to find it to download from anywhere and publish to the feed.
Please help to resolve this issue or guide me to find the package in the internet.
Thanks in advance.
~Sreeni

Where did you download the nuget package microsoft.identity.serviceessentials.aspnetcore 1.26.0 ?  Looks like it's not hosted in nuget org. Is it developed by your/your team or hosted on third-party  feed?

Yes, its not found in nuget sites, looks like its developed by the client, I guess.
However what' the work eround to get the package - Microsoft.Identity.ServerAuthorization or upgrade root package to the higher versions. Please guide

If this package is developed by the client, you can try to navigate into the package folder(%userprofile%.nuget\packages\microsoft.identity.serviceessentials.aspnetcore) and search files similar to README to find any links about download/Documentation/Release notes to get where it's hosted.
Or find the file .nupkg.metadata and open it to get the source value like this:{
"version": 2,
"contentHash": "",
"source": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
}

Let me check, thanks for the suggestion..

If you find any files related to source location, you can share them with us.

@SreeniC I am hitting the same issue. Were you able to figure this one out?

Answering my own question, I had to add the upstream azure-feed://msazure/Official@Local to our feed
